# English expression for "cold-natured" without emotional connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I speak Persian, and in our language we have a word for a person who more often feels cold than warm (or reverse). The person tends to be cold even when others around them feel warm or when they experience higher temperatures.
I was trying to find an English equivalent for this word, and I came across the expression "cold-natured" (and hot-natured as antonym). However, I think cold-natured can also mean cold-hearted or someone without soft emotions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'cold-natured' (by editing your question). English has the concept of someone being cold emotionally, but without knowing what the Persian concept means, I don't know whether *coldness* in the two languages correspond.

Comment: @Lawrence, I've updated my question.
I mean a person who is sensitive to cold, who feels it more often, even when others feel warm.

Comment: I don't think we have a single word for this. Maybe we can use yours?

Comment: If you're just talking about feeling *physically cold*, then sometimes people would say "cold blooded", but this more commonly is used to describe someone lacking in sympathy/empathy (eg "cold-blooded killer") so it's not a great choice.  I am not aware of a better term.  In the north of England, where i am from, we would sometimes joke about how people in the south can't tolerate coldness, which is kind of what you're talking about it, but there was no single word for it.

Comment: Your question reminds me of the mythical [salamander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salamanders_in_folklore_and_legend), which was supposed to be cold enough to safely live in a fire.

Comment: @NEO In that case, a slight modification of your phrase works well in English: "sensitive to *the* cold".

Comment: @MaxWilliams, Yes I mean physically cold. But I don't think cold-blooded is the right word, because it refers to the animals having a body temperature varying with that of the environment; poikilothermics.

Comment: That is true, but i don't think many people would think that was what you meant if you said cold-blooded about a person:  ie nobody would think you were literally saying they were a reptile!  They might however think that you were saying they were lacking in emotion or sympathy.

Comment: "She's sensitive to (the) cold" is how I translate the Italian *è freddolosa*, which literally means  "she's coldish" but in English that denotes someone who is unemotional, unfeeling and distant.

Comment: Thin blooded used to be used for those who couldn't take the cold.  I guess it isn't used anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Nesh**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nesh) *adjective* describes something as very weak and sensitive to cold. It is rarely used, so it might not be easily understood by the listener.

An alternative is **perpetually cold**. Or in simple terms "always cold".

A **perpetually cold person** is someone who feels cold while others don't; turns off the AC while others don't want to; stays home bundled in the warmest attire even for the slightest temperature drop outside.

You can guess what a **perpetually warm** person is, then.

This might not be a proper name for such a person, but it is popular on the internet.

Some interesting posts can be read here:

1. [10 Times Perpetually Cold People Really Lose It During The Winter](http://elitedaily.com/life/cold-people-lose-it-winter/1309296/)
2. [12 Struggles of Dating Someone Who’s Perpetually Cold](http://www.puckermob.com/relationships/12-struggles-of-dating-someone-whos-perpetually-cold)
3. [13 Things Only Perpetually Cold People Will Understand](http://www.buzzfeed.com/haleyc13/13-things-only-perpetually-cold-people-will-unders-jiey#.owzza2nDB)

<sub>If this condition worsens, it is best to consult a doctor because there might be [some serious underlying health issues.](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/why-am-i-cold)</sub>

Comment: +1 Nice find with "nesh," imo! I knew French had one word for it (“frileux/euse,” which curiously also has the “timid” sense), but I got nothing but “sensitive to (the) cold” and “overcautious” trying to work backwards from “frileux.”

Comment: +1 When the flight attendant tries to get my jacket, I say "No thanks, I am always cold."

Comment: Well, thats my [secret.](http://i.memecaptain.com/gend_images/ESd8cQ.jpg)

Comment: @NVZ, Yes this exactly what I was looking for. Do you happen to know a word for a person who is perpetually warm?

Comment: I've never come across this word, written or spoken, so i don't know how useful it is.

Comment: @MaxWilliams there's a first time for everything. :)

Comment: Perhaps, but if the questioner says it to a british-speaking person they will assume it is a word from his own language, which is a fail.

Comment: @MaxWilliams that I can't disagree. OP is better off using "sensitive to cold" then.

Answer (score 4):

**Cold-natured does not mean 'feels colder than other people'.**

It is only used to refer to their emotional and psychological makeup. Someone's 'nature' is their core being. (Incidentally 'hot-natured' and 'warm-natured' mean different things. A 'warm-natured' person is caring and sensitive. A 'hot-natured' person is impetuous and fiery.)

Phrases that indicate that someone feels cold all the time might include:

- **cold-blooded** (which can also mean cold-natured). This is from comparison between 'warm-blooded animals (which can regulate their own body temperature) and cold-blooded ones (which can't)
- **cold-sensitive** (or 'sensitive to cold')
- **feels the cold** (thanks Chris H)

Comment: "Feels the cold" is a little hidden in your answer, but I think it's the best the OP is going to get.

Comment: I agree - if you say "nesh" everyone is going to assume it's a word from your own language, whereas if you say "feels the cold" everyone will understand that you mean the person in question is more vulnerable to feeling cold than the average person.

Comment: 'Cold-blooded' would be more likely taken as metaphor for 'ruthless'

Answer (score 3):

How about ***thin-blooded***?

> *The colloquial term I would use to describe someone who always feels cold when everyone else finds the temperature to be comfortable is **thin-blooded***. [WordReference Forums](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-be-cold-easily.3028729/)

Answer (score 2):

People who are always cold are often said to have **poor circulation**.

Your core body temperature is 37 degrees celsius, maintained by burning food. Your blood flow takes this heat and distributes it to the rest of your body. hence good circulation = all of your body getting warm from blood that's been heated in your core; poor circulation = a cold body, and you'll feel the cold more easily.

The phrase is probably overused, and used in medically inaccurate situations, but I suggest that it is widely understood (in the UK at least) to mean "someone who is always cold".